# Get distinct ids for each group value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have a result-set as following:

```
client_id   status
------------------
67          1
67          0
67          0
67          0
77          0
```

I need to get only those `client_id` whose `latest (top)` entry is `0`.

I tried following but get both `67 and 77`. `67` should be excluded.

```
SELECT DISTINCT client_id FROM
(
    SELECT client_id, status FROM client_history 
    WHERE (DATE(updated_on) BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') 
    ORDER BY DATE(updated_on) DESC
) as ch
WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY client_id
```

How to set condition so that I can get only those records whose `status` is 0?

Comment: that's my query and I know it is wrong.. hence I need you guys to help me to get to desired result. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest entries, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select ch.*
from client_history ch
where ch.updated_on = (select max(ch2.updated_on)
                       from client_history ch2
                       where ch2.client_id = ch.client_id and
                             date(updated_on) between ? and ?
                      );
```

Note that this uses parameter placeholders (`?`) rather than string substitution to pass in values.

To this, you can just add:

```
and status = 0
```

for the filtering that you want.

Answer (score 1):

use correlated subquery with not exists

```
select distinct client_id
from lient_history a
where not exists (select 1 from lient_history b where a.client_id=b.client_id 
  and status=1) 
and (DATE(updated_on) BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below one, I think it will solve your issue.

```
Declare @FromDate Date, @ToDate Date
Set @FromDate = -- whatever date range you wanted to give
Set @ToDate =  -- whatever date range you wanted to give
SELECT DISTINCT client_id FROM dbo.Client_history 
WHERE cast(updated_on as DATE)>=@FromDate and cast(updated_on as DATE)<=@ToDate
AND status = 0
ORDER BY DATE(updated_on) DESC
```